# ASP.NET Core 3.1 Web application failed with 'Microsoft.NETCore.App', version '3.1.27' was not found error

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2019, asp.net-core-3.1

I have a slightly older single project asp.net core 3.1 web application that compiles fine, but when launch, it fails with the `'Microsoft.NETCore.App', version '3.1.27' was not found` error.

I searched online a while, found several suggestions, one most common one is to install the 3.1.27 Runtime, I've checked via my Visual Studio Installer that .Net Core 3.1 runtime and all its dependencies are installed.

I went to this web site: `https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet/3.1`
to download and installed the .NET Core 3.1.27 runtime.
When I run `dotnet --info`, here are my settings:

```
.NET Core SDK (reflecting any global.json):
 Version:   3.1.403
 Commit:    9e895200cd

Runtime Environment:
 OS Name:     Windows
 OS Version:  10.0.19044
 OS Platform: Windows
 RID:         win10-x64
 Base Path:   C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\3.1.403\

Host (useful for support):
  Version: 3.1.9
  Commit:  774fc3d6a9

.NET Core SDKs installed:
  3.1.403 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]

.NET Core runtimes installed:
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.All 2.1.23 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.All]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.All 2.1.30 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.All]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.1.23 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.1.30 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 3.1.9 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 3.1.27 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.1.23 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 3.1.9 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 3.1.9 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]
```

One suggested to add `<RuntimeFrameworkVersion>3.1.27</RuntimeFrameworkVersion>`
to the project file, I tried that, still the same error.

I noticed that in my project, under Dependencies\Frameworks, it listed both `Microsoft.AspNetCore.App` and `Microsoft.NETCore.App`, as one can see, I do have 3.1.27 under the `AspNetCore.App` folder, but not under `NetCore.App` folder, so I tried to manually copy that 3.1.27 folder over into the NetCore.App folder, still failed.

Comment: Are there any exclamation icons on the dependencies anywhere? Any warnings after a rebuild solution? Anything in the output after rebuild solution worth noticing?

Comment: Did you try to clean the solution. Remove all 'obj' and 'bin' directories and do a full rebuild of the solution?

Comment: Yes, I did clean and rebuild

Comment: .. and remove 'obj' and 'bin' directories?

Comment: Yes, I tried remove 'obj' and 'bin' directories, then rebuild, still failed with same error.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I "fixed" it:

manually copy and paste the

`C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\3.1.9\` folder

to

`C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\3.1.27\` folder

Now the application runs/launch without error.

I am thinking if one starts out a new project with the newer framework from scratch, might not have this type of problems.